# How to find sets of rows with one or more fields matching and assign a set id for each matching set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have a requirement to find sets of rows where one or more fields are matching.

E.g:

Vendor Master

```
VendorId    |    VendorName   |   Phone     |   Address   |    Fax    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                AAAA              10101           Street1         111
2                BBBB              20202           Street2         222
3                CCCC              30303           Street3         333
4                DDDD              40404           Street2         444
5                FFFF              50505           Street5         555
6                GGGG              60606           Street6         444
7                HHHH              10101           Street6         777
```

```
SELECT VendorId FROM VendorMaster vm
WHERE EXISTS
   ( Select 1 FROM VendorMaster vm1
     WHERE vm1.VendorId <> vm2.VendorId
     AND (vm1.Phone = vm2.Phone OR vm1.Address=vm2.Address OR vm1.Fax = vm2.Fax)
```

With the above query I am getting records, but my requirement is to assign a set-id for each set of matching records.

Like below:

```
SetId     |  VendorId
---------------------
 1000             1
 1000             7        //1 and 7- Phone numbers are matching
 1001             2
 1001             4        //2 and 4 - Address matching
 1001             6        // 4 and 6 - Fax matching
```

Please advise me on how to write a query to **assign set ids for matching sets**. The performance of the query is also key here as the number of records will be around 100,000.

Thanks

Comment: This is more easily done in client code, than in SQL.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, now I am doing it with client side code, but it is very slow for huge volume of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will give you your desired result. A little explanation is in the comments, let me know if more is needed.

```
with relations 
--Get all single relationships between vendors.
as (
    select t1.vendorId firstId,
        t2.vendorId secondId
    from VendorMaster  t1
    inner join VendorMaster  t2 on t1.vendorId < t2.vendorId and(
            t1.Phone = t2.Phone
            or t1.address = t2.address
            or t1.Fax = t2.Fax
            )
    ),
recurseLinks
--Recurse the relationships
as (
    select r.*, CAST(',' + CAST(r.firstId AS VARCHAR) + ',' AS VARCHAR) tree
    from relations r

    union all

    select r.firstId,
        l.secondId,
        cast(r.Tree + CAST(l.secondId AS varchar) + ',' as varchar)
    from relations l
    inner join recurseLinks r on r.secondId = l.firstId and r.tree not like '%' + cast(l.secondId as varchar) + ',%'

    union all

    select r.firstId,
        l.firstId,
        cast(r.Tree + CAST(l.firstId AS varchar) + ',' as varchar)
    from relations l
    inner join recurseLinks r on r.secondId = l.secondId and r.tree not like '%' + cast(l.firstId as varchar) + ',%'
    ),
removeInvalid
--Removed invalid relationships.
as (
    select l1.firstId, l1.secondId
    from recurseLinks l1
    where l1.firstId < l1.secondId
    ),
removeIntermediate
--Removed intermediate relationships.
as (
    select distinct l1.*
    from removeInvalid l1
    left join removeInvalid l2 on l2.secondId = l1.firstId
    where l2.firstId is null
    )
select result.secondId,
    dense_rank() over(order by result.firstId) SetId
from (
    select firstId,
        secondId
    from removeIntermediate 

    union all

    select distinct firstId,
        firstId
    from removeIntermediate 
    ) result;
```

The 'relations' named result set returns all VendorMasters relationships where they share a common Phone, Address or Fax. It also only returns [A,B] it won't return the reverse relationship [B,A].

The 'recurseLinks' named result set is a little more complex. It recursively joins all rows that are related to each other. The path column keep track of lineage so it won't get stuck in an endless loop. The first query of this union selects all the relations from the 'relations' named result set. The second query of this union selects all the forward recursive relationships, so given [A,B], [B,C] and [C, D] then [A,C], [A,D] and [B,D] are added to the result set. The third query of the union selects all the non forward recursive relationships, so given [A,D], [C,D], [B,C] then [A,C], [A,B] and [B,D] are added to the result set.

The 'removeInvalid' named result set removes any invalid intermediate relationships added by the recursive query. For Example, [B,A] because we will already have [A,B]. Note this could have been prevented in the 'recurseLinks' result set with some effort.

The 'removeIntermediate' named result set removes any intermediate relationships. So given [A,B],[B,C], [C,D], [A,C], [A,D] it will remove [B,C] and [C,D].

The final result set selects the current results and adds in a self relationship. So given [A,B], [A, C], [A,D] add in [A,A]. Which produces are finial result set.

Comment: It looks like the recursive join was messed up. Take a look at this. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be7da/9/0

Comment: This is awesome and perfect! 
@Will -You are a genius man. Thanks a lot :)
Added few more rows http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28cc1/1

Comment: I am unable to understand the query fully. If you don't mind could you explain? Thanks

Comment: I added some comments at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, now I understood the query and learnt new things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [Ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) to accomplish this. For example, for unique Address values:

```
DECLARE @VendorMaster TABLE ( VendorID INT, Vendorname VARCHAR(20), Phone VARCHAR(20), Address VARCHAR(20), Fax VARCHAR(20) )
INSERT INTO @VendorMaster
  (VendorID, Vendorname, Phone,   Address,   Fax )
VALUES
  (1,        'AAAA',     '10101', 'Street1', '111'),
  (2,        'BBBB',     '20202', 'Street2', '222'),
  (3,        'CCCC',     '30303', 'Street3', '333'),
  (4,        'DDDD',     '40404', 'Street2', '444'),
  (5,        'FFFF',     '50505', 'Street5', '555'),
  (6,        'GGGG',     '60606', 'Street6', '444'),
  (7,        'HHHH',     '10101', 'Street6', '777')

SELECT 
  DenseRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Address )
 ,* FROM @VendorMaster
```

Results

```
DenseRank   RowNumber   VendorID    Vendorname  Phone   Address Fax
1   1   1   AAAA    10101   Street1 111
2   2   2   BBBB    20202   Street2 222
3   3   3   CCCC    30303   Street3 333
2   4   4   DDDD    40404   Street2 444
4   5   5   FFFF    50505   Street5 555
5   6   6   GGGG    60606   Street6 444
5   7   7   HHHH    10101   Street6 777
```

If these SetId values need to persist, you could create a separate table with an identity column to track the values associated with each SetID for each set up. It sounds like you may simply want to normalize your database and break out data elements being duplicated into their own tables linked by an identity column relationship.

Comment: this query gives only for Address field, but my requirement is to get ranking based on one or more matching fields. Can it be done?

Comment: You can include more than one field in the OVER ( ORDER BY ... ) clause if you wish to include more fields.  For example,  DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Address, Phone ) would group Address + Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Although Wills answer is pretty ingenious, I've never really like recursive CTE's very much because they always work great on small sets but become very slow on larger ones quickly and sometimes will hit the MAXRECURSION limit.

Personally I'd try to solve this by first putting every VendorID in its own SetID and then merge the upper SetIDs into lower SetIDs that have a matching Vendor.

It would then look something like this:

```
-- create test-code
IF OBJECT_ID('VendorMaster') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE VendorMaster
GO

CREATE TABLE VendorMaster
    ([VendorID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, [Vendorname] nvarchar(100), [Phone] nvarchar(100) , [Address] nvarchar(100), [Fax] nvarchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO VendorMaster
    ([Vendorname], [Phone], [Address], [Fax])
VALUES
    ('AAAA',     '10101', 'Street1', '111'),
    ('BBBB',     '20202', 'Street20', '222'),
    ('CCCC',     '30303', 'Street3', '333'),
    ('DDDD',     '40404', 'Street2', '444'),
    ('FFFF',     '50505', 'Street5', '555'),
    ('GGGG',     '60606', 'Street6', '444'),
    ('HHHH',     '10101', 'Street6', '777'),
    ('IIII',     '80808', 'Street20', '888'),
    ('JJJJ',     '90909', 'Street9', '888');

GO
-- create sets and start shifting & merging
DECLARE @rowcount int

SELECT SetID = 1000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VendorID),
       VendorID
  INTO #result
  FROM VendorMaster

SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq0 ON #result (VendorID)

WHILE @rowcount > 0
    BEGIN
        -- find lowest SetID that has a match with current record
        ;WITH shifting
           AS (SELECT newSetID = Min(n.SetID), 
                      oldSetID = o.SetID
                 FROM #result o
                 JOIN #result n
                   ON n.SetID < o.SetID
                 JOIN VendorMaster vo
                   ON vo.VendorID = o.VendorID
                 JOIN VendorMaster vn
                   ON vn.VendorID = n.VendorID
                WHERE vn.Vendorname = vo.Vendorname
                   OR vn.Phone = vo.Phone
                   OR vn.Address = vo.Address
                   OR vn.Fax = vo.Fax
                GROUP BY o.SetID)
        UPDATE #result
           SET SetID = s.newSetID
          FROM #result upd
          JOIN shifting s
            ON s.oldSetID = upd.SetID
           AND s.newSetID < upd.SetID

        SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

    END

-- delete 'single-member-sets' for consistency in compare with CTE of Will
DELETE #result 
  FROM #result del
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM #result xx
                     WHERE xx.SetID = del.SetID
                       AND xx.VendorID <> del.VendorID)

-- fix 'holes'
UPDATE #result 
   SET SetID = 1 + (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SetID)
                      FROM #result xx
                     WHERE xx.SetID < upd.SetID)
  FROM #result upd

-- show result
SELECT * FROM #result ORDER BY SetID, VendorID
```

When running this on the test-case provided, I get the same results as the CTE, although it takes a bit longer.

When I add some extra test-data, things become interesting though.

```
DECLARE @counter int = 7

WHILE @counter > 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT VendorMaster ([Vendorname], [Phone], [Address], [Fax])
        SELECT [Vendorname] = NewID(), 
               [Phone]      = ABS(BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 1500, 
               [Address]    = NewID(), 
               [Fax]        = NewID()
          FROM VendorMaster 

        SELECT @counter = @counter - 1
    END

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VendorMaster
```

This gives me 1152 test-records with the matches we already had before, but now also with some matches on Phone (the NewID()'s will not ever match) to make things more easy to verify.

When I run the query above on this, I get 604 sets in just shy under 2 seconds. However, when I run the CTE on it, it

Comment: Hmm.. it seems part of my post got chopped of.. oh well, the conclusion was something along the lines of: this approach works for bigger test-sets than the recursive CTE; but it becomes quite slow quite quickly too... Good luck.